# jQgrid - how can I custom format the contents of a cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jQuery grid to create a table online.
I want to add bold and italics to some text in one of my cells and I also want to show the ellipsis if the content is too much.

The current cell content is:

> [Mary Doe] :- Can this be done soon?

And I want it to be displayed as:

> **[Mary Doe] :**- Can this be done soon?

Further if the content exceeds I want it to be concatenated by ellipsis.

Here is link to jsfiddle if you want to use that:
https://jsfiddle.net/jo1qrysq/

```js
var Data = [{"identification":"2001","created_date":"2017-09-25 05:48:50","quantity":1,"summary":"Require to rebuild","product":"D245","loc":"SG","assignee":"Hello World","requestor":"John Doe","status":"Requested","comments":"[Hello World] :- We do not have sufficient quantity","priority":"High","comment_on":"2017-09-26 05:00:18"},
{"identification":"2002","created_date":"2017-09-25 05:48:50","quantity":5,"summary":"Require to paint","product":"A205","loc":"MY","assignee":"Bye World","requestor":"Mary Doe","status":"In Progress","comments":"[Mary Doe] :- Can this be done soon?","priority":"High","comment_on":"2017-09-26 05:00:18"}
];

$(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
      colNames:['ID','Comment','identification','Priority', 'Qnty', 'Summary', 'Product','Location','Assignee','Status'],
        colModel: [
            {name:'auto_id', key: true, width:18, hidden: true},
            {name: "comments"},
            { name: "identification",search:true, formatter: 'dynamicLink'},
            { name: "priority"},
            { name: "quantity" },
            { name: "summary" },
            { name: "product" },
            { name: "loc" },
            { name: "assignee" },
            {name: "status"}],
            data: Data,
            rowNum:20,
            rowList:[20,40,60],
            loadonce: true,
            toppager: '#pager2',
            autowidth : true,
            gridview: true,
            height: "auto",
            ignoreCase: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            caption:"A Table"      
    });
});
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
    <table id="grid"></table>
```

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar I have added the code here as well. It is in both places. I am using jsfiddle so that people can play with the code without needing to set up much. JSFIDDLE is a popular tool and people are familiar with it as compared to stack snippets.

Comment: You can still use a stack snippet to make your code here executable, so people don't have to go to the other site.

Answer (score 0):

`<td>[Mary Doe] :- Can this be done soon?</td>` can be changed to `<td><strong>[Mary Doe] :-</strong> Can this be done soon?</td>`, or replace 'strong' with 'b'.

As for ellipsis, see [this css property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp), `text-overflow: ellipsis;`

https://jsfiddle.net/jo1qrysq/1/

Comment: Actually my question is more toward how to edit the jQuery cell content. I understand the HTML/CSS required. How do I introduce it in the contents of the cell. Or do I manipulate my JSON first and then feed it?

Comment: @CoderBC in the jsfiddle I created, I changed the JSON to include the <strong> tag around [Mary Doe] and that worked.

Comment: yeah but is there some other way in jQuery grid, than changing my JSON

Comment: You will have to do the same thing, whether you do it in the JSON or in the grid. You have 2 options: (1) iterate over your JSON objects, find each "comments" property, and wrap the text in your strong tags, or (2) iterate over the appropriate cell in each row of your Table, and do the exact same thing. I would say the first option is marginally simpler but it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to implement your requirements. For example you can add `text-overflow: ellipsis` rule on all cells of jqGrid:

```css
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/jo1qrysq/3/

You can define CSS rule like

```css
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td.myellipsis {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

and to use `classes: "myellipsis"` property in some columns of jqGrid. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/jo1qrysq/5/

You use free jqGrid work, which supports autoresizing of columns based on the width of content. You can use the settings like

```js
autowidth : true,
autoresizeOnLoad: true,
cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true },
autoResizing: { compact: true, resetWidthOrg: true },
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/jo1qrysq/8/

You can combine different approaches. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/jo1qrysq/6/ and https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/jo1qrysq/7/